# sudo nautilus error

Tags: nautilus, ibus

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10.  When I run `sudo nautius` in the terminal this error appears:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(nautilus:2904): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/mahsa/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare'  returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there an actual problem? What are you trying to do and how is it failing? Does `nautilus` appear? Why are you running it with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install nautilus to solve your problem , if you dont want to spend time solving it .

```
sudo killall nautilus

sudo apt-get purge nautilus

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nautilus
```