# Nautilus is extremly slow to start, no errors in terminal

Tags: nautilus

Starting today, Nautilus is taking forever to start (around 25-35 seconds)

Originally I got a missing directory error, and I followed a guide to fix it. It fixed the missing directory error, but not the slowness. Now the terminal gives me zero errors when I launch Nautilus, but it's still slow. I would like to know why this is.

Comment: I got the error from this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452234/sudo-nautilus-error

The answer there worked, now I have no errors in the terminal

Comment: This problem may be related to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224555

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: If you're using [samba](https://www.samba.org/) in some ways like with printers, you will have to reinstall and configure it. You will also have to reconfigure `nautilus`.**

`samba` and `nautilus` are working together. And if you start installing `samba` yourself and tweaking with it, you may experiment this issue. Even if you launch `nautilus` in a terminal, this will print no error.

The lazy solution is to purge, purge and reinstall.
Avoid removing directories yourself because you may break your system, use `apt` :

```bsh
sudo apt purge samba samba-* nautilus
sudo apt install nautilus
```

By the end, with a working `nautilus`, you will have the dependency `samba-libs` installed.

Finally, I suggest you to install this `nautilus` extension:

```bsh
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```